# how to put variables on the vertical end points of curly brace

Tags: delimiters

I need a LaTeX code that shows variables on the vertical end points of curly braces.

[image]

Comment: `\}_{b}^{a}` should work (in math mode).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the following five solutions may satisfy your typesetting requirements:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
      \}_a^b         \quad 
  \big\}_{\!a}^{\!b} \quad 
  \Big\}_{\!a}^{\!b} \quad 
 \bigg\}_{\mkern-4.5mu a}^{\mkern-4.5mu b} \quad 
 \Bigg\}_{\!\!a}^{\!\!b}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Just how much the upper and lower endpoints should be shifted to the left, i.e., *towards* the curly braces (via `\!` and `\mkern` instructions), depends on the math font that's in use. The kerning numbers shown in the code above should be (more or less) OK for `Computer Modern`. If you were to use a `Times Roman` clone and, in particular, the `mtpro2` package (short for MathTime Professional II), less (negative) kerning would be advisable:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\[
      \}_{\mkern-1.5mu a}^{\mkern-1.5mu b}  \quad 
  \big\}_{\mkern-3mu   a}^{\mkern-3mu   b}  \quad 
  \Big\}_{\mkern-3.5mu a}^{\mkern-3.5mu b}  \quad 
 \bigg\}_{\mkern-4mu   a}^{\mkern-4mu   b}  \quad 
 \Bigg\}_{\mkern-4.5mu a}^{\mkern-4.5mu b} 
\]
\end{document}
```